# Create array from values in an array

Tags: php, arrays

This is highly similar to a previous question ([Create an array from multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730359/create-an-array-from-multidimensional-array)), yet in this case I do not have a multidimensional array. Here is what I have:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ratings Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [rating] => 4.4
        )

    [1] => ratings Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [rating] => 5.0
        )

    [2] => ratings Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [rating] => 5.0
        )
)
```

What I'm attempting to do is create a new array that consists of only the "rating" values...

```
$result_array = array(0 => "4.4",
                      1 => "5.0",
                      2 => "5.0");
```

The following solution was unsuccessful since $value is an object rather than an array...

```
$result_array = array();

foreach ($array as $value) {
    $result_array[] = $value[1];
}
```

What's the correct way to go about it?

Comment: As there're 3 elements in `$array` there will be three iterations in a loop. What do you expect?

Comment: Amal - still don't know. Was waiting on your answer. You answered the original question so I gave you the check mark for that at least

Comment: Nevermind, very stupid mistake on my part. I was running the print_r within the foreach loop. All is good now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result_array[] = $value[1];
```

With the above line, you're trying to use `$value` as an array when it's not. It's an object, so treat it as such.

The properties of an object can be accessed using arrow notation (`->`). The updated code would read:

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $result_array[] = $value->rating;
}
```